# Passing a variable in django class based views by extracting the value from a different model

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have two models namely categoreis and products. on my home page I have listed multiple categories and when I click on any category I want to open new page where products belonging to that category are displayed.
I am passing the category_id through the url to products view page. but what I want to extract the category.title by using the category_id and the category model so that I can display it on top of products page.
I have attached the code of my model

```
    class category(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
description = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True, blank=True )
category = models.ForeignKey(category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
cost = models.PositiveIntegerField()
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
    self.slug = slugify(self.name)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

the best I could do is append the category_id to context, but it isn't helpul in anyway.

```
class products(ListView):
model = product
template_name = 'products/productList.html'
context_object_name = 'products'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(products, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['category'] = self.kwargs['cat_id']
    return context
```

the url looks like this:

```
    path('<int:cat_id>', products.as_view(), name = 'products'),
```

The output I want should look like this:
[image: output_image]
I referred to some stackoverflow questions but couldn't find anything helpul.

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the queryset with the value for the category:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = product
    template_name = 'products/productList.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return (
            super()
            .get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
            .filter(category_id=self.kwargs['cat_id'])
        )
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PascalCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Product`</s> to `product`.

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `ProductListView`, instead of <s>`products`</s>.

---

> **Note**: Normally you should *not* change slugs when the related fields change. As is written in the article [*Cool URIs don't change* <sup>[w3.org]</sup>](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI), URIs are *not* supposed to change, since these can be bookmarked. Therefore the slug should only be created when creating the object, not when you change any field on which the slug depends.

Comment: Thankyou for response and suggestions. I have one doubt that in the get_queryset, we have not provided the model name 'category' so how will this code work. and also can you please tell me how should we extract the data (category name) from context in template.

Comment: @shubdb: you can also pass it to the context like you did, but the filtering happens in `get_queryset`, so that is where you filter `Post`s based on the `cat_id`.

Comment: can you elaborate a little on what you are suggesting and how it's gonna work. Acutally I am a beginner in django and have done some basic projects on it. And I am not able grasp what is it that you are suggesting.

Comment: @shubdb: you can, as in your question, pass the `cat_id` to the template. For the `get_queryset`, we just filter the `Product` objects, such that `products` will only contain `product`s with that `cat_id` as `category`...